# Why is value set correctly even though we use different locks in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

Why is `value` set correctly even though we use different locks in different threads?

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {
    static String a = "LOCK";
    static String b = "LOCK";
    int id;
    static int value = 0;

    MyThread(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (id == 0) {
            synchronized (a) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Main.N; i++)
                    value = value + 3;
            }
        } else {
            synchronized (b) {
                for (int i = 0; i < Main.N; i++)
                    value = value + 3;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    static final int N = 100000;
    static int ITER = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[2];
        boolean sw = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < ITER; j++) {
            MyThread.value = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                threads[i] = new Thread(new MyThread(i));
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                threads[i].start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                try {
                    threads[i].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (MyThread.value != 2 * 3 * N) {
                System.out.println("i was different than " + 2 * 3 * N + ", it is " + MyThread.value);
                sw = false;
            }
        }
        if (sw)
            System.out.println("Something is strange");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume that a thread safety bug is guaranteed to reveal itself?  Practically the definition of thread safety bugs is that they can happen to work okay until they don't.

Comment: One *possible* reason is that the first thread finishes before the second one even starts.

Comment: @jack you need the calling code for context. Without it, the answer could be "because the threads run one after the other".

Comment: @AndyTurner Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java string literals are interned to save memory.

Your two `"LOCK"` strings (and therefore the two objects you lock on) are actually the same object.

This is (one of the reasons) why you should never lock on primitives.

Comment: I am so blind :(

Comment: And at the very least, `new Object()` is a superior choice for an object to synchronize on than any other. Although investing the time into learning `java.util.concurrent.locks` is definitely going to pay dividends!!

Answer (score 4):

Never use `String` as locks as there may well be the same instance of an other `String` because of the string pool.

In your case, your two `"LOCK"` strings are actually the same object.

Comment: The first sentence is the general case: 2 `String` -with the same content- *may* be the same object if they have both been *interned* and therefore should not be used as locks.